# How to get input text field values in print preview?

Tags: javascript

Here is a sample code what I am trying to fix. In print screen I am not able to see the text which is entered in `input` text field. Any solution will be appreciated.

```
 var divToPrint=document.getElementById('div1Id');

 if (divToPrint != null && divToPrint != "") {
   var newWin=window.open('','Print-Window');
   newWin.document.open();
   newWin.document.write('<html><body onload="window.print()">'+divToPrint.innerHTML+'</body></html>');
   newWin.document.close();
   newWin.close();    
 }
```

Comment: `divToPrint.innerHTML` should be `divToPrint.value` as you want to get the actual value from that input

Comment: input text field has no `innerHTML` property, you should use `.value` to get input text value

Comment: NB: `divToPrint` would never equal a string, (`!=""`) since it's the result of a call to `getElementById`, which returns an element or null. Your condition can simply be `if (divToPrint) {`.

Comment: thanks for reply. divToPrint is a ID of div which contains many input text fields and tables and all , in preview it is showing only empty text boxes instead the value what text box contains !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use jquery.print.js library and call this function in your custom function $.print("#id");

Answer (score 0):

Textbox and Checkbox controls you have to get `value` instead of InnerHtml

```
   var divName = document.getElementById('div1Id')
    var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
    var inpText = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
    var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
    printContents += inpText;

    newWin.document.open();
    newWin.document.write('<html><body 
    onload="window.print()">'+printContents+'</body></html>');
    newWin.document.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have this `script`

```
 var divToPrint=document.getElementById('div1Id');

 if (divToPrint != null && divToPrint != "") {
   var newWin=window.open('','Print-Window');
   newWin.document.open();
   newWin.document.write('<html><body onload="window.print()">'+divToPrint.innerHTML+'</body></html>');
   newWin.document.close();
   newWin.close();    
 }
```

where you copy the inner html, however, the value is not there. Let's make sure the values are correct, like this:

```
 var divToPrint=document.getElementById('div1Id');

 //Gather input values and inputs
 var inputValues = [];
 var inputs = divToPrint.getElementsByTagName("input");
 for (var index = 0; index < inputs.length; index++) inputValues.push(inputs[index]);

//Generate script of page
var script = 'var inputValues = ' + JSON.stringify(inputValues) + ';';

script += 'var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");' +
          'for (var index = 0; index < inputs.length; index++) ' +
          'inputs[index].value = inputValues[index];';

 if (divToPrint != null && divToPrint != "") {
   var newWin=window.open('','Print-Window');
   newWin.document.open();
   newWin.document.write('<html><body onload="' + script + 'window.print()">'+divToPrint.innerHTML+'</body></html>');
   newWin.document.close();
   newWin.close();    
 }
```

Code is untested, please let me know if there is a typo.

Comment: as i specified in my previous comment divToPrint is ID of div which contains table ,text fields etc. manually setting all fields values in script is bit long process, any other way to solve this

Comment: @krish how many milliseconds did it take? How many inputs do you have?

Comment: got solution using .print() ( jQuery.print.js )..thanks for the reply

Comment: @krish how many milliseconds did it take? How many inputs do you have?

Comment: sorry i did not tried for manual scripting for adding all values

Comment: @krish then how do you know it is slow?

Comment: see i have many components in my page and that too some component may be added dynamically so i cant write script to set the each value right?

Comment: @krish I am still not convinced. If by "many" you mean 1000, then it should be peanuts for your browser. And I am also not convinced that the method you accepted does not do just this under the hood.