# HTML Popup window print

Tags: javascript, html, printing, popup

I have a pop up window with several input boxes. I am trying to print that window using `window.print()` but all boxes appear empty on print preview.

HTML:

```
<div class="div_popup" id="item_card">  
   <div class="pop_div_header" id="ic_header"> 
      <a id="pop_item_num" style = "color: whitesmoke">Quote Information for: </a>
      <button class="btn_pop" onclick="pop_up_close('item_card')" style="background-image: url(/images/btn_close.png)"></button>
      <button class="btn_pop" onclick="pop_up_print('item_card')" style="background-image: url(/images/print_pop.png)"></button>
   </div>

   <fieldset id="item_card_quote_info" style="height: 25%; width: 95%; padding: 0%; margin:1%; ">
      <legend class="dash_text" style="margin-left: 1%; margin-right:3%; margin-bottom: 0.5%; padding-top: 0%"> Quote Information </legend>
      <a style="color:whitesmoke; font-weight: bold; margin:1%"> Unit Summary </a>
      <input id="ic_bq_unit_final_cost" type="text">         
   </fieldset>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function pop_up_print(){
   var printContents = document.getElementById('item_card').innerHTML;
   document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
   window.print();
}
```

I appreciate any guidance. Thanks in advance

Comment: innerHTML does not copy input values.

Answer (score 0):

You can try and use this

```
printDivCSS = new String ('<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/tablesorter.css" type="text/css" />') <!--this is the css for the part to be printed. In my case i wanted to print a table including its CSS-->

function printDiv(divId) {
    window.frames["print_frame"].document.body.innerHTML=printDivCSS + document.getElementById(divId).innerHTML
    window.frames["print_frame"].window.focus()
    window.frames["print_frame"].window.print()
}
```

Add this link to prompt print:

```
<a href=javascript:printDiv('div_print') title="Print Report">Print </a> 

<div id="div_print" style="width:100%">
<!--include all the contents to be printed here-->

</div><!--this ends the part you want to print-->
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Add this link to prompt print

<a href=javascript:printDiv('div_print') title="Print Report">Print </a> 

<div id="div_print" style="width:100%">
//include all the contents to be printed here

</div><!--this ends the part you want to print-->

Hope it helps

Comment: I can't see where you use iframe

Answer (score 0):

You can store input value in variable and retrieve it before print.

```
<input id="ic_bq_unit_final_cost" type="text" onchange="setValue()">
```

**JS**

```
var store_val = "";
function pop_up_print() {
  var printContents = document.getElementById('item_card').innerHTML;
   document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
   document.getElementById('ic_bq_unit_final_cost').value = store_val;
   window.print();
}
function setValue() {
    store_val = document.getElementById('ic_bq_unit_final_cost').value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried it but results are the same. Input box appears empty on print preview

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out with help from this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45457424/how-to-get-input-text-field-values-in-print-preview) with slight modifications for my case.

```
function pop_up_print(){
   let divToPrint =  document.getElementById('item_card')
   let inputValues = [];
   let inputs = divToPrint.querySelectorAll("select, input");
   for (var index = 0; index < inputs.length; index++) {
       inputValues.push(inputs[index].value) 
   }
   let printContents = document.getElementById('item_card').innerHTML;
   let originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
   document.body.innerHTML = printContents 
   let inputsp = document.querySelectorAll("select, input");
   for (var index = 0; index < inputsp.length; index++) {
       inputsp[index].value = inputValues[index];
   }
   window.print(); // print (modal)
   document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
}
```